# Turn on Multiple Layers in one click

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to turn on multiple layers at once? I have around 100 shapefiles which are turned off by default on entry. Turning the folder on/off makes no difference and you can’t select multiple layers using Ctl then turn them all on and off.

Comment: There are a few options in the View menu: Show all layers, Hide all layers ...

Comment: Perfect thank you. I didn’t think to look in the menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even an easier way in the layer panel: select "Manage map themes" (the eye-symbol) and click on "show all layers" (see screenshot). Other options: hide all layers, show or hide selected layers, Hide Deselected Layers. You can even pre-define visibility presets, so-called Map Themes, so that you can change with one click between different configurations of layer visibility.

See here for the documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#configuring-map-themes

[image: Show all layers]